# How to properly use a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I just recently started programming for `iOS/iPhone`.  I thought I knew what I was doing until `XCode5/iOS7` came around.  Previously, I created a class derived from `UIViewController` with a `XIB`, added a label, and programatically added it to the `rootWindow:`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ... // boilerplate code
    MyViewController* myRoot = [[MyViewController alloc]init];
    self.window.rootViewController = myRoot;
```

To use a navigation bar, I changed the code slightly:

```
MyViewController* myRoot = [[MyViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController* navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
[navigationController pushViewController:myRoot animated:YES];
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

This seemed to work fine.  However, on `iOS 7` the controls at the top of my custom view controller appear to be behind the navigation bar.  Some googling resulted in [this link](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/developers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar/) which describes changes in the status bar.

It also seems to indicate that,
 A) `UINavigationController` should handle the changes automatically
 B) "auto layout" should handle the changes automatically,

and that I shouldn't need to worry.  However, my sample app above doesn't appear to handle anything automatically.

I also found some other sample code which uses the controller differently: adding the navigation controller's view as a `subView` to an existing view.  This sort of makes sense for adding a navigation controller later on in an app's lifetime, but I am trying to set one up on launch.

Am I using the `UINavigationController` correctly?

What do I need to consider for `iOS7` vs. earlier versions?

How do I configure "Auto Layout" (I don't see this in interface builder anywhere)?

Comment: You were using a .xib file and not Storyboards, right?

Comment: @race_carr Yes, just a .xib file and no storyboards.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile.  self.viewController, and self.navigationController are not valid properties of the AppDelegate object.

Comment: Changing code to something that compiles, results in the same problem:- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    
    MyViewController* myController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController* myNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myController];
    self.window.rootViewController = myNav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}